# How to access to application of a Django project from html?

Tags: html, django

while clicking on an element of my navbar I want to access to another application of my django project  which is named aps . for example accueil and s'authentifier are working normally but graph return 404 not found . On the other side when I run 127.0.0.1:8000/aps it works .
base.html

```html
{% load staticfiles %}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <title>Temperature sensor </title>
                <!-- Core CSS - Include with every page -->
                <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
                </head>
                <body>
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/accueil">Accueil </a>
                                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index">Graphe </a>
                                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/login">S'authentifier </a>
                                
                            </div>
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Account
                                            <span class="caret"></span>
                                        </a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="/mail">changer mail</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#">changer temps</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="divider"></li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>

                {% block content %}
                {% endblock %}


                    <!-- Core Scripts - Include with every page -->
                    <script src = "{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
                    <script src = "{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
        {% block javascript %}
        {% endblock %}


            </body>
        </html>
```

aps/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rasp import foo
import json 
def index(request):
  return render(request, 'index.html', {'t' : foo()})
```

aps//urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

 ]
```

Comment: Do you have a URL defined for /index then?

Comment: yes  look at my edited question

Comment: Er, that does not show a URL defined for /index.

Comment: do u mean urls of my whole project ?

Comment: You tell me. You are the one with a link to /index in your HTML, and you are telling us it is not working. Now, where have you defined an entry in urls.py that responds to that path?

Comment: Sorry I haven't paid attention that I am calling index in the html file instead of aps . Any way ,thank you for your help